# Failing jdbc INSERT INTO statement to MS Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access, jdbc

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO countrylookup (Country, DialCode) VALUES('Iran', '957')")
```

**Running this statement gives me no error output in the console, but when I check the database no update/insert is made. What could be the reason for this?**

The access to the database itself is successful, and fetching values with a statement such as SELECT * FROM countrylookup succeeds.

I tried the preparedStatement approach aswell with the exact same result. The file is not open when I execute the command.

UPDATE: Stacktrace: (first row in Swedish means "INSERT INTO-expression contains the following unknown fieldname: 'Pa_RaM000'. Please check that the name is rightly spelled and try again.)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Drivrutin f?r ODBC Microsoft Access] INSERT INTO-uttrycket inneh?ller f?ljande ok?nda f?ltnamn: 'Pa_RaM000'. Kontrollera att namnet ?r r?ttstavat och f?rs?k igen.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at MDBAccessor.insertValueIntoField(MDBAccessor.java:43)
at TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the INSERT INTO statement to actually be reflected in the database you have to call connection.commit() followed by connection.close(). Another similar thread describing this: [Java General Error On Insert...???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584951/java-insert-help)

Answer (score 1):

Is dialcode numeric? If so, remove the quotes from the value.

```
VALUES('Iran', 957)
```

Comment: That didn't make a difference. Is there a way to debug this?