# what does this Exception mean ??java.sql.SQLException: General error , in Java with Access DB?

Tags: java, ms-access

I'm trying to insert data into the Access DataBase stored on my computer, 
but when i run this following code an Exception appears

This is the exception:

> Dec 14, 2011 7:22:21 PM Ass3_lab.afterLogin$8 actionPerformed
>       SEVERE: null
>       java.sql.SQLException: General error
>           at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6986)
>           at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
>           at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3110)
>           at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:338)
>           at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:288)

I wrote this method to make the insertion:

```
public void saveDataInDB(int std_id,int course_id,String semester_no) throws SQLException {  
    Connection conn=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;

    String insertSQL="insert into Registered_course (std_id,course_id,semester_number) values(? , ?,?)";
    try{
        conn=con.getConnection();
        pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

        pstmt.setInt(1,std_id);
        pstmt.setInt(2,course_id);
        pstmt.setString(3,semester_no);
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }  // end of try
    finally {
        if(conn != null){
            conn.close();
        }
        if (pstmt != null) {
            try {
                pstmt.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And i called the method like this inside an action Listener:

```
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            Login l = new Login();  

            for(int t=0;t<=numberOfRowsInTableOne;t++){
                i.saveDataInDB(l.idFromDB,course_id[t],semester_no);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(afterLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Could someone help me solving this problem please?

Comment: Assuming its homework I tagged it accordingly...

Comment: you are closing the connection and statement twice, try removing from "try" and see. also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4584951/922954) - you may need to commit the connection too.

Comment: @  mprabhat ,yup it is , thank you :)

Comment: @aishwarya , thank you for the link , i will check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeneralError is quite misleading. There are various reasons why it can happen:

1. Incorrect username, password.
2. Difference in bitness of Java and ODBC drivers (check if both java and your odbc drivers are either 32 or 64)
3. Very annoying but recreating DSN works (no idea why but it sometimes it does).

Comment: where can i check the bitness of my java and ODBC drivers ??

Comment: java -version will give you the version along with bit of your jdk, odbc driver will depend on your machine so if your machine is 32 your odbc driver will be 32 bit or else 64.

Comment: I don't know ,seems my problem happens because of the last reason you talked about . anyway thank you