# Get Table Data and Save Onto Database - SQLEXception General Error

Tags: java, sql

I've Made an Inventory system using java swing.
My Code Works Fine until I added these lines of code into my SAVE Button:

This was supposed to:

GEt DATA from Table and Save it onto Database

1. Upon Button Click,get Data per Row in my Incoming Table
2. Set Row Data in a String Array per Column
3. Insert These Data into my Table IncomingTransactionITems

   ```
   int rowCount=jTable3.getRowCount();
           String[] ItemList=new String[6];
           for(int rowctr=1;rowctr<rowCount;rowctr++){
                ItemList[0]= String.valueOf(rowctr);                 //    Incoming Transaction_Number
                ItemList[1]= this.jTextField1.getText();             //    Transaction ID
                ItemList[2]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString();              //    Item Number
                ItemList[3]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 2).toString();              //    Quantity
                ItemList[4]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 3).toString();              //    Unit Price
                ItemList[5]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 4).toString();              //    Total Price     

   //                    Save onto IncomingTransactionItems Table in Database                   
               String sqlItems="INSERT INTO IncomingTransactionItems(Incoming_Transaction_Number, Transaction_ID,Item_Number, Quantity, Unit_Price,Total_Price)values('"
               + ItemList[0]+"','"              //    Incoming Transaction_Number
               + ItemList[1]+"','"              //    Transaction ID
               + ItemList[2]+"','"              //    Item Number
               + ItemList[3]+"','"              //    Quantity
               + ItemList[4]+"','"              //    Unit Price
               + ItemList[5]+"')";              //    Total Price       

                try{
                   pst= conn.prepareStatement(sqlItems);
                   pst.execute();

                   this.UpdateJTable();

               }
               catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                  Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
               }
   ```

   But When I run the Program It Throws an **Exception**:

   ```
   Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch cmdADDMouseReleased
   SEVERE: null
   java.sql.SQLException: General error
   ```

I thought that my database might be Read Only so I checked the other Functions of the System (i.e. ADD ITEMS, LOGS, Update PriceList etc.)
Still Working Fine.

I checked the Incoming Transaction Number-Primary Key of My Table, If I Might be SAving a duplicate Value but It does not because the Program gets the Number of Values in the Table and Increments it by one for a new record.

The Error Points that this Line is the Problem

```
pst= conn.prepareStatement(sqlItems);
```

Am I Missing Something or AM I doing Something Wrong?

**EDIT**

posting my whole code for the button

```
if(cmdADD.isEnabled()){
        //==================UPDATE ITEM COUNT and PRICE===================
        int rowCountloop=jTable3.getRowCount();
        float PreviousPrice;
        float NewPrice;

        for(int rowctr=1;rowctr<rowCountloop;rowctr++){

            //          get Item Count
            int ItemQuantity=Integer.valueOf(this.jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr,1).toString());
            int IncomingQuantity=Integer.valueOf(this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 2).toString());

            //          add incoming Items
            int ItemTotal=ItemQuantity+IncomingQuantity;

            PreviousPrice=(Float.valueOf(this.jTable2.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr,2).toString()));
            NewPrice=(Float.valueOf(this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 3).toString()));
            float newTotalPrice=((float) ((PreviousPrice*ItemQuantity)+(NewPrice*IncomingQuantity))/ItemTotal);

            //          convert values to 2 decimal
           double PreviousPrice2 = Math.round(PreviousPrice*100.0)/100.0;
            double NewPrice2 = Math.round(NewPrice*100.0)/100.0;
            double newTotalPrice2 = Math.round(newTotalPrice*100.0)/100.0;
            //          Update Value of Quantity and Price

            //                String sqlUpdate= "Update allItems set Quantity='"+ItemTotal+"',Unit_Cost='"+NewPrice2+"',Total_Cost='"+newTotalPrice2+"' where Item_Number='"+this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString()+"'";
           String sqlUpdate= "Update allItems set Quantity=?,Unit_Cost=?,Total_Cost=? where Item_Number='"+this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString()+"'";
            try {
                PreparedStatement pstUpdate= conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);
                pstUpdate.setInt(1, ItemTotal);
                pstUpdate.setDouble(2, NewPrice2);
                pstUpdate.setDouble(2, newTotalPrice2);
                pstUpdate.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Inventory_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            //==================SAVE Price Change to PriceList==========================================

                String sqlPriceChange="insert into PriceList(PriceID,ItemNumber,NewPrice,PreviousPrice,DateAndTime)values(?,?,?,?,?)";
                 try (PreparedStatement pstPriceChange = conn.prepareStatement(sqlPriceChange)){    
                pstPriceChange.setString(1, "PL"+ (PriceIDtxt.getText())+"-"+rowctr);
                pstPriceChange.setString(2,this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString());
                pstPriceChange.setDouble(3,NewPrice2);
                pstPriceChange.setDouble(4,PreviousPrice2);
                pstPriceChange.setString(5, (dateFormatwithtime.format(date)));

                pstPriceChange.executeUpdate();

            }
            catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }// end of loop
        //==========================================================================================
        int RowCounter=jTable3.getRowCount();

        if(RowCounter<=1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Input Data on Incoming List","System Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Confirm and SAVE?", "System Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                 if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {  
                int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Data Cannot be modified once it is SAVED, Continue?", "System Message", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            int rowCount=jTable3.getRowCount();
            String[] ItemList=new String[6];
            String sqlItems="INSERT INTO IncomingTransactionItems(Incoming_Transaction_Number, Transaction_ID,Item_Number, Quantity, Unit_Price,Total_Price)values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            for(int rowctr=1;rowctr<rowCount;rowctr++){
                 ItemList[0]= String.valueOf(rowctr);                                               //    Incoming Transaction_Number
                 ItemList[1]= this.jTextField1.getText();                                           //    Transaction ID
                 ItemList[2]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString();              //    Item Number
                 ItemList[3]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 2).toString();              //    Quantity
                 ItemList[4]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 3).toString();              //    Unit Price
                 ItemList[5]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 4).toString();              //    Total Price        

    //                    Save onto IncomingTransactionItems Table in Database                   


                try (PreparedStatement pstInsert = conn.prepareStatement(sqlItems)){
    // You could do this with a for-loop, I've done it long
    // to demonstrate the use of PreparedStatement
                pstInsert.setString(1, ItemList[0]);
                pstInsert.setString(2, ItemList[1]);
                pstInsert.setString(3, ItemList[2]);
                pstInsert.setString(4, ItemList[3]);
                pstInsert.setString(5, ItemList[4]);
                pstInsert.setString(6, ItemList[5]);
                pstInsert.executeUpdate();
                 }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                   Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }

                                   String sql="INSERT INTO Incoming_Transactions (Transaction_ID, Date_Delivered, Ref_No, PO_No,JO_No, Supplier_Code,Notes, Status, Time_Stamp )\n" +
                                                        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";





                try (PreparedStatement pstTransactions = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){    
                pstTransactions.setString(1, (this.TransactionNotxt.getText()));
                pstTransactions.setString(2,  this.DateDeliveredChooser.getDate().toString());
                pstTransactions.setString(3,this.ReferenceTxt.getText());
                pstTransactions.setString(4,this.POtxt.getText());
                pstTransactions.setString(5, this.JOtxt.getText());
                pstTransactions.setString(6, this.SupplierCodetxt.getText());
                pstTransactions.setString(7, this.NoteTextArea.getText());
                pstTransactions.setString(8, "Processed");
                pstTransactions.setString(9, dateFormatwithtime.format(date));
                pstTransactions.execute();



                }
                catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                    Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
//                  update Table to show changes
                this.UpdateJTable();
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Transaction Saved");
            this.cmdADD.setEnabled(false);
            this.cmdDELETE.setEnabled(false);
            CountDataPriceList(); // Increment Price List number
                    }
                }
        }

    }
```

Here is the Full Error

```
    run:
Jul 16, 2015 1:19:31 PM Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch cmdADDMouseReleased
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: General error
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6993)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:137)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch.cmdADDMouseReleased(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:1240)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch.access$3600(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:44)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch$30.mouseReleased(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:915)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Jul 16, 2015 1:19:31 PM Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch cmdADDMouseReleased
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch.cmdADDMouseReleased(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:1278)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch.access$3600(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:44)
at Inventory_System.Encoding_Incoming_Batch$30.mouseReleased(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.java:915)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

BUILD STOPPED (total time: 1 minute 45 seconds)
```

Comment: Start by reading how [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to see how you're suppose to actual use `PreparedStatement`s

Comment: Since you're using MS Access, could you also provide the table definations?

Comment: You might want to include the full stack trace of the error

Comment: You might consider having a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584951/java-general-error-on-insert)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions which now solved my Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PreparedStatement` is suppose to be used with place markers (`?`) for the actual values, which helps prevent SQL injection attacks, but also allows you to think less about the encoding required to pass different types of values (like `int`, `double` and `Date` for example).

So, instead of specifiying the actual values in your `sqlItems`, you provide a abstract query with place holders, for example...

```
String sqlItems="INSERT INTO IncomingTransactionItems(Incoming_Transaction_Number, Transaction_ID,Item_Number, Quantity, Unit_Price,Total_Price)values(?,?,?,?,?, ?)"
```

You then "bind" the value for each column to the statement...

```
pst.setString(1, ItemList[0]);
```

Where `1` represents the first wildcard, `2` the second, so on and so forth (remember, this is NOT `0` indexed, it is `1` indexed, where `1` is the lowest possible value).

So, it might look more like this...

```
int rowCount=jTable3.getRowCount();
String[] ItemList=new String[6];
String sqlItems="INSERT INTO IncomingTransactionItems(Incoming_Transaction_Number, Transaction_ID,Item_Number, Quantity, Unit_Price,Total_Price)values(?,?,?,?,?, ?)"
for(int rowctr=1;rowctr<rowCount;rowctr++){
     ItemList[0]= String.valueOf(rowctr);                 //    Incoming Transaction_Number
     ItemList[1]= this.jTextField1.getText();             //    Transaction ID
     ItemList[2]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0).toString();              //    Item Number
     ItemList[3]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 2).toString();              //    Quantity
     ItemList[4]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 3).toString();              //    Unit Price
     ItemList[5]=this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 4).toString();              //    Total Price     

     try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlItems)){
        // You could do this with a for-loop, I've done it long
        // to demonstrate the use of PreparedStatement
        pst.setString(1, ItemList[0]);
        pst.setString(2, ItemList[1]);
        pst.setString(3, ItemList[2]);
        pst.setString(4, ItemList[3]);
        pst.setString(5, ItemList[4]);
        pst.setString(6, ItemList[5]);
        pst.executeUpdate();
    }
    catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
       Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
this.UpdateJTable();
```

This also means that you could do something more like...

```
pst.setLong(1, rowctr);
pst.setString(2, (String)this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 0));
pst.setInt(3, (int)this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 1));
pst.setInt(4, (int)this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 2));
pst.setDouble(5, (double)this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 3));
pst.setDouble(6, (double)this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(rowctr, 4));
```

And seed the column values with the required data type (I'm guessing at the actual types here)

You should also be calling `executeUpdate` instead of `execute`, it can provide you with more information about the operation (such as the number of rows that were effected)

Have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details

> I checked the Incoming Transaction Number-Primary Key of My Table, If I Might be SAving a duplicate Value but It does not because the Program gets the Number of Values in the Table and Increments it by one for a new record.

It would be wise to use a auto increment key and not include the primary key in your insert statements if possible, this overcomes possible thread race conditions

Based on the information from [Java General Error On Insert...???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584951/java-general-error-on-insert), you may have uncommitted changes in your current connection which is causing issues with subsequent updates to fail

Assuming that the `Connection` is set to [`autoCommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)), you could simply use the `try-with-resources` block to automatically close the connection (and `PreparedStatement`)

```
try (Connection conn = ) {
    String query = "...";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        if (stmt.executeUpdate() == 0) {
            System.err.println("Possible error with update, did not update any rows");
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Otherwise you should `commit` the update manually

```
try (Connection conn = ) {
    String query = "...";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        if (stmt.executeUpdate() == 0) {
            System.err.println("Possible error with update, did not update any rows");
        } else {
            conn.commit();
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank You for providing a fast answer.. I'll change my code to what you suggested here. I'll notify you if this solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I've Changed my code and it's still giving out a general Exception Error. I'll Edit My Question and I'll Post My Whole code For My Button.

Comment: @MikeAgustin What database are you using?  Try printing the sql statement and printing the values you are binding to check that they are what you expect.  Also, you should make sure that the connection is still alive and valid

Comment: Forgot to Tell You There are Four SQL statements in my button. 2 of them works fine. the third is in my question here and the fourth throws a Data type mismatch in criteria expression Error. Im Posting the Whole Button code now.

Comment: I am using MS access database, I tried printing the sql seems like its working fine. It just stuck in the ExecuteUpdate area where it throws an error

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: This is the code I use in my DB.Connect() Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

Comment: Funny Thing is , The first 2 queries execute fine but the other 2 does not.. even if they are in the same button

Answer (score 0):

Based on [MadProggrammer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) I recreated my code using proper Prepared Statements and I also used **Batch Insert in JDBC**

after several trial and errors I found out that this line causes the **General Error** problem:

```
pst.setString(1, this.jTextField1.getText());
```

I was saving the data in the **SAME** Incoming_Transaction_Number which is my Primary key for the IncomingTransactionNumber table. This causes the general error.

So I changed my Incoming_Transaction_Number Column back to **AutoNumber** and let the DB do the numbering for me.

Thanks to [MadProggrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) who helped me in this. So I Will Accept his Answer. And Posted my answer for clarification.

```
public void saveData() throws SQLException{
    //==========================================================================================


//            save Incoming Transaction Items based on Transaction ID
            conn=Database.getConnection();

            String sqlItems="INSERT INTO IncomingTransactionItems( Transaction_ID,Item_Number, Quantity, Unit_Price,Total_Price)values(?,?,?,?,?)";

//                    Save onto IncomingTransactionItems Table in Database                   

                 pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlItems);
                try{

               int rowctr=jTable3.getRowCount();  

               for(int row=1;row<rowctr;row++){

      //          pst.setString(1, this.jTextField2.getText());  // removed this line and set autonumber in my database

                pst.setString(1, (this.TransactionNotxt.getText()));
                pst.setString(2, this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
                pst.setString(3, this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
                pst.setString(4, this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 3).toString());
                pst.setString(5, this.jTable3.getModel().getValueAt(row, 4).toString());

                pst.addBatch();
                this.jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(this.jTextField2.getText())+1));
               }

               pst.executeBatch();
                 }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
                   Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }finally{
                     try {
                         pst.close();
                         conn.close();

                     } catch (SQLException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(Encoding_Incoming_Batch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                     }
                }
}
```